# How to divide a div's two contents into two columns

Tags: html, css

I have 3 paras inside a div. I want them firstly to be on right of the image in column form. this am able to acheive. Now what i want is, for para 2 and 3, i want them to be in form of column, on left is para 2 and on right para3. I tried using `display flex + flex-direction` properties, but its not working, obv am missing some smaller details being a beginner. Your help would be appreciated.

my code:

```css
section{
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 10rem 9% 2rem;
}

/*** ------- ABOUT -------- ***/
.about {
    padding: 40px 0;
}

.about-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.about-img {
    flex:  1;
    padding: 20px;
}

.info-right{
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
}

.about-title {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.info-p1, .info-p2, .info-p3 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* IRRELEVANT TO ISSUE */
/*
.home {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.home-content{
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
}

.home-content h1{
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin: -3px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: slideRight 1s ease forwards;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.home-content p {
    font-size: 1rem;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: slideLeft 1s ease forwards;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    color: grey;
}

.home-img {
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.home-img img {
    width: 35vw;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: zoomIn 1s ease forwards;
    animation-delay: 2s, 3s;
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
*/
```

```html
<section class="about" id="about">
    <div class="about-container">

            <div class="about-img">
                <img src="images/car1-2.jpg" alt="service">
            </div>

        <div class="info-right">    

        <div class="about-info">
            <h3 class="about-title">Our Story</h3>
            <p class="info-p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.
            </p>
            <div class="para-column">
            <p class="info-p2">Nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
                dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            <p class="info-p3">Nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
                dolor in reprehenderit in dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Post your CSS attempt with it.

Answer (score 1):

Nested flexbox (as per this snippet)?
[CSS columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)?

```css
section{
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 10rem 9% 2rem;
}

/*** ------- ABOUT -------- ***/
.about {
    padding: 40px 0;
}

.about-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.about-img {
    flex:  1;
    padding: 20px;
}

.info-right{
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
}

.about-title {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.info-p1, .info-p2, .info-p3 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.para-column {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="about" id="about">
    <div class="about-container">

            <div class="about-img">
                <img src="http://picsum.photos/300" alt="service">
            </div>

        <div class="info-right">    

        <div class="about-info">
            <h3 class="about-title">Our Story</h3>
            <p class="info-p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.
            </p>
            <div class="para-column">
            <p class="info-p2">Nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
                dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            <p class="info-p3">Nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
                dolor in reprehenderit in dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</section>
```